# Oracle Complex Sort - Multiple Children

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a table as follows:

```
BRAND_ID PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_DESC PRODUCT_TYPE
100      1000       Tools        A
100      1500       Tools        A 
200      2000       Burgers      B
300      3000       Clothing     C
300      4000       Makeup       D
300      5000       Clothing     C
```

So a Brand can have multiple products, all of the same type or mixed types. If a brands products are all of the same type I need them first in the result, sorted by product type, followed by brands that have different product types. I can do this programatically but I wanted to see if there is a way to do it in the query.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to Oracle, but I believe something along these lines should work...

```
WITH
  ranked_data
AS
(
  SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT product_type) OVER (PARTITION BY brand_id)  AS brand_rank,
    MIN(product_type)            OVER (PARTITION BY brand_id)  AS first_product_type,
    *
  FROM
    yourTable
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ranked_data
ORDER BY
  brand_rank,
  first_product_type,
  brand_id,
  product_type,
  product_description
```

An alternative is to JOIN on to a sub-query to calculate the two sorting fields.

```
SELECT
  yourTable.*
FROM
  yourTable
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    brand_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT product_type) AS brand_rank,
    MIN(product_type)            AS first_product_type,
  FROM
    yourTable
  GROUP BY
    brand_id
)
  AS brand_summary
    ON yourTable.brand_id = brand_summary.brand_id
ORDER BY
  brand_summary.brand_rank,
  brand_summary.first_product_type,
  yourTable.brand_id,
  yourTable.product_type,
  yourTable.product_description
```

Answer (score 1):

How about selecting from a sub-select that figures out number of distinct brands and then sorting by the count?

```
select t.BRAND_ID, 
       t.PRODUCT_ID, 
       t.PRODUCT_DESC, 
       t.PRODUCT_TYPE
  from (select t2.BRAND_ID, 
               t2.PRODUCT_ID, 
               count(distinct t2.PRODUCT_TYPE) cnt
          from YOURTABLE t2
         group by t2.BRAND_ID, t2.PRODUCT_ID) data
  join YOURTABLE t on t.BRAND_ID = data.BRAND_ID and t.PRODUCT_ID = data.PRODUCT_ID
 order by data.cnt, BRAND_ID, PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_TYPE
```

Comment: Not quite what I need but it's close. What I need is a count of the distinct product_types by brand_id (I think that's OVER in Oracle). The product_id and desc are irrelevant although I do want to display them. Then I can order by cnt, brand_id